# What would be the case if we overstay in UAE 96 hours transit visa?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, uae, emirates

Actually, I would reach UAE on 9th April 9:00 AM from Jeddah and my flight from UAE to another city is on 14th April 2:00 AM.

My travel agent issues me a 96 hours transit visa (I really don't know why) and my stay duration is around 110 hours.

My question is what would be the worst case if I stay around 110 hours which is more than 96 hours obviously?

Need suggestions that should I go with it or change my flight and make my stay inside 96 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UAE offers two transit visas, both of which have to be applied for through your airline. They're valid for 48 hours(free), or 96 hours(AED50). They're not renewable or extendable.

[Source](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/transit-visa)

Based on your itinerary above, you won't have a valid visa for your trip. Most likely, you'll be denied boarding by your airline.

If you do get to the UAE you could be denied entry, in which case you'll be returned to your point of departure, or if that's not possible, sent to some country that will accept you.

If you are allowed to enter, you'll probably be stopped by immigration as you leave for overstaying your visa.

I'm sure you don't want any of that to happen. Change your flight(s) or get your travel agent to apply for an appropriate visa or entry permit.

**Note:** You haven't given any details of your nationality, nor where you're flying from or to. You might be eligible for a visa on arrival which is valid for 14 days. More details [here](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am from Pakistan and would be returning to Karachi from UAE.

Comment: You can also apply for the 30-day tourist visa through the airline, Emirates or flydubai.